# wait for findInbackground to finish in different class before returning parse result

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have a class that handles all the parse calls such as findInBackground - the class name is ParseCalls.
And in a fragment I call a function in the ParseCalls class - that use the findInBackground function.
I want to wait for the findInBackground function to finish and then return the value from the function to the fragment (whcih will change the ui in it)

The problem is that it doesnt.
Before the findInBackground the function return the value null;

```
public Player getPlayerParse(String id) {
        ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Players");
        query.whereEqualTo("index", id);
        try {
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                 if (e == null) {
                    for(ParseObject object : objects)
                        players.add(new Player(object.getString("index")));
                 } 
              }                     
            });              
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return player;
    }
```

thank you!

Comment: That is some terrible code, you should look at the subclass feature of Parse.com instead of hacking between ParseObject and Player types yourself. Does your posted code even compile? You return 'player' but cannot see any variable with that name

Comment: Can answer your questions by the way, but I am on my mobile atm. Would like you to ensure that the code is compiling before answering, so please let me know when you have updated the code.

Comment: @cYrixmorten His code seems ok.

Comment: @user3100708 1) the method returns a single Player yet he creates a list of players 2) He manually creates a list of Player objects (could be done automatically using subclassing) 3) Finally he makes a `return player` but there is no variable called `player` defined in the shown code 4) `query.findInBackground` starts a async network lookup, so `return player` is called before the query even completes ... so I do not agree with the code being ok.. but again, if @fofo clarifies the code (at least makes it compile), I will be happy to give an answer.

Comment: Start a new thread, inside that call findInfBackground(). As, in your case code is ok, but it doesn't wait for parsing. Starting a new thread, will perform UI operation in front, and at the back, findInBackground() fetch the result.